# Can memory imported to Vulkan from another API be freed by Vulkan?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

On POSIX systems, one can import memory objects from other APIs through file descriptors using `VkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR` (it works similarly on Windows using `VkImportMemoryWin32HandleInfoKHR`). Once the memory object has been imported, is Vulkan allowed to free the underlying memory with `vkFreeMemory`, or can the memory only be freed by the API that has allocated it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Vulkan is not merely allowed to free the `VkDeviceMemory` object; it is *required* to do so. When you import memory into Vulkan, the specification is clear that Vulkan now *owns* that handle:

> Importing memory from a file descriptor transfers ownership of the file descriptor from the application to the Vulkan implementation. The application **must** not perform any operations on the file descriptor after a successful import.

So you're not allowed to use regular commands on that file descriptor anymore. Vulkan owns it, and calling `vkFreeMemory` on it is not optional:

> VkDevice objects can be destroyed when all VkQueue objects retrieved from them are idle, and all objects created from them have been destroyed. This includes the following objects:
>
> ...
>
> - VkDeviceMemory

No exception is made for `VkDeviceMemory` objects allocated as the result of an memory import operation.

Now of course, you can perform operations on a different FD that just so happens to be talking to the same memory (you can even use `vkGetMemoryFdKHR` to do so). But the specific FD you imported becomes owned by Vulkan. Freeing the memory frees the file descriptor; it doesn't affect the memory itself.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that excerpt from the spec states that Vulkan is required to free the memory. From my understanding, it just says that you aren't allowed to do anything with the *file descriptor* (for example, call `close()` on it) after you imported the memory because Vulkan now owns the *file descriptor*, but not necessarily the *memory*.

Comment: @malte-v: Because you have to free all `VkDeviceMemory` objects you allocate. There is no special exception for imported memory, and I can't quote a thing that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, in case you import memory from another API, you don't allocate it, right? Or is it copied rather than shared?

Comment: @malte-v: The function you used to import it is literally called `vkAllocateMemory`.

Comment: I had a look at VK_KHR_external_memory once again and it says this: "An application may wish to **reference** device memory in multiple Vulkan logical devices or instances, in multiple processes, and/or in multiple APIs. This extension enables an application to export non-Vulkan handles from Vulkan memory objects such that the **underlying resources** can be **referenced** outside the scope of the Vulkan logical device that created them." So, the memory isn't duplicated on import, and there is no new memory allocated. I think they just reused `vkAllocateMemory` to not introduce a new function.

Comment: @malte-v: From the standard: "*`VkDevice` objects can be destroyed when all `VkQueue` objects retrieved from them are idle, and all objects created from them have been destroyed. This includes the following objects: ... VkDeviceMemory ...*" There is no exception made for device memory objects allocated as the result of an import process. All `VkDeviceMemory` objects are treated equally except when it is specifically stated otherwise.

Comment: @malte-v: You're too closely associating the backing storage of the memory from the `VkDeviceMemory` object *itself*. With a few exceptions, every Vulkan object you create you must destroy with the appropriate call. Whether this process actually annihilates the backing storage for that object is *irrelevant*. So it doesn't matter if a specific `VkDeviceMemory` object happens to have backing storage that will continue to exist after the `vkFreeMemory` call; you still *must call it*.

Comment: That makes sense. Probably, the memory must be freed in both APIs. However, it still matters to me what really happens when I `vkFreeMemory` imported memory. Does that mean "I don't need this memory any more on the Vulkan side but other APIs may still need it" or "I don't need this memory any more in any way and it can safely be overwritten"?